# Windows Phone 8.1 Textbox Color Style

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need the colors of the following Themes `Light`, `Dark` and `HighContrast` for the `Textbox` of Windows Phone 8.1.

I found the color-definitions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710191.aspx), but I think they are mainly for Windows Store Apps, because Blend shows me some differences at the `Textbox`-Colors. But I only got some Colors at Blend and dont know how to get all of them for my `Textbox.`

Please help me to get the right colors!

Comment: you mean the textbox foreground color?

Comment: For Example, but I need every Color. Can I extract the Color Definitions in Blend?

Comment: you can find the staticresource names for the colors when you edit the template of the `TextBox` in blend